# reshaping the data from wide to long

Tags: r, reshape

Please help me with the following matter
I have a wide data frame that I need to reshape.
This is the df I have

```
mydf <- data.frame(date=1983:1985,January=c(5,7,8),February=c(12,18,19))  
mydf
```

this is the output I need

```
output <- data.frame(date=rep(c(1983,1984,1985),each=2),Month=rep(c("January","February"),3),Value=c(5,12,7,18,8,19))
output
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -date, names_to = 'Month', values_to = 'Value')
#  date    Month Value
#1 1983  January     5
#2 1983 February    12
#3 1984  January     7
#4 1984 February    18
#5 1985  January     8
#6 1985 February    19
```

Comment: It worked conveniently. Thank you so much bro.

Answer (score 0):

Using `melt` from `reshape2`:

```
reshape2::melt(mydf, id.vars = "date", measure.vars = c("January", "February"), variable.name = "Month", value.name = "Value")

 #  date    Month Value
 #1 1983  January     5
 #2 1984  January     7
 #3 1985  January     8
 #4 1983 February    12
 #5 1984 February    18
 #6 1985 February    19
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My prolem is solved. Thanks again for the consideration.